# A kind of Minkowski inequality for integral

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, lp-spaces

> **Problem:** Let $f$ be a measurable nonnegative function on $[0,1]^2$, and $1\leq r < p < \infty$. Then, show that
>   $$ \left(\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}f^{r}(x,y)dy\right)^{p/r} \right)^{1/p} \leq \left(\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}f^{p}(x,y)dy\right)^{r/p} \right)^{1/r}.$$
>   Hint : Let $s=\frac{p}{r}$ and  $F(x) = \int_{0}^{1}f^{r}(x,y)dy$ and consider appropriate function $h \in L_{s'}[0,1].$

**My attempt:** By following hints, I've got this result. For any $h \in L_{s'}[0,1],$ from the Tonelli's theorem,

$$ \int_{0}^{1}F(x)|h(x)|dx = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f^{r}(x,y)dy|h(x)|dx = \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f^{r}(x,y)|h(x)|dxdy, $$
and by using the Holder's inequality,
$$ \int_{0}^{1}\int_{0}^{1}f^{r}(x,y)|h(x)|dxdy \leq ||h||_{s'}\int_{0}^{1}||f^{r}(x,y)||_{s}  = ||h||_{s'}\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}f^{p}(x,y)dx \right)^{r/p}dy.$$

However, now I have no idea how to proceed. I know that 
$$||F||_{s}^{1/r} = \left(\int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}f^{r}(x,y)dy\right)^{p/r} \right)^{1/p} $$
so I tried to choose suitable $h \in L_{s'}[0,1]$ with $||h||_{L_{s'}[0,1]}$ such that $$\int_{0}^{1}F(x)|h(x)|dx =||F||_{s}.$$
If we find such function, than $$||F||_{s} \leq \int_{0}^{1}\left(\int_{0}^{1}f^{p}(x,y)dx \right)^{r/p}dy$$
so we are done by taking $1/r$-th root.

However I haven't find yet. If you gave me one more step for this problem, I would appreciate much about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: choose $h(x)=F(x)^a\left\lVert F\right\rVert_s^b$ for some well chosen parameters $a$ and $b$.

Comment: I think a=s-1, b=1-s solves the last part. I really appreciate your help :)