# Minkowski's Integral Inequality

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

I need to prove and inequality in Lp-spaces. Let (X,$\mathcal{S},\mu)$ and $1<p<+\infty$. Let $f:X\times X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the y-section $f^{y}$ is $p$-integrable and further,

$$\int_{X} ||f^{y}||_{p} d\mu(y) < +\infty$$

Define, for all $x \in X$,

$$ g(x) = \int_{X} f(x,y)d\mu(y) $$.

I need to show that

$$ ||g||_p \le \int_{X} ||f^{y}||_{p} d\mu(y) $$

In other words,

$$\Bigg(\int_{X} \Bigg| \int_{X}f(x,y) d\mu(y)   \Bigg|^{p} d\mu (x) \Bigg)^{1/p} \le \int_{X} \Bigg( \int_{X} |f(x,y)|^{p}d\mu(x) \Bigg)^{1/p} d\mu(y) $$

I was thinking in using Fubini's Theorem, and the fact that $\Big|\int_{X}  f d\mu \Big| \le \int_{X} |f|d\mu$, but in general cases it doesn't seem to be useful.

Can somebody help me? :c

ADDED:

Acording with @Kabo Murphy 's answer, this is the Minkowski's Integral Inequality. The best proof I could find is here, but need some modifications: [A kind of Minkowski inequality for integral](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2589723/a-kind-of-minkowski-inequality-for-integral)

Following the last link, I was wondering:

a) Why does $||h||_{s'} = 1$ if $h \in L_{s'}[0,1]$?

b) Does it hold in general that $\int_{X}g(x)|h(x)|d\mu(x) = ||g||_{p}$ where $g(x) = \int_{X} f(x,y)d\mu(y)$ and $h(x) = g(x)^{p-1}||g||_{p}^{1-p}$?

Seems routine, but I couldn't find a proof :C

Answer (score 1):

This is just Minkowski's inequality for integrals whose proof are easily available on the net. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_inequality for example.

Comment: I don't see any sum of functions anywhere, how is this Minkowski's inequality?

Comment: @Math1000 Minksowski's inequality **for  integrals** is not the basic Minksowski's inequality for sums.

Comment: Oh, I see there is a separate "Minkowski's integral inequality" on that page. Never mind.